# fish: Iterate over an array/list

Tags: fish

How can you do an array literal? I tried:

```
for x in (635 35710 653 30420 29835 35004)                                                                       
   echo $x
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's much simpler than you tried: `for x in 635 35710 653` will work.

Think of `for` as another command that receives *arguments*, and arrays always expand each element to one argument - so just passing it like that will have the same effect as a (theoretical) more specialized array literal would.

Comment: I'm having issue getting themes to work.  It was crashing on an older version, also now the fonts aren't working right so even though it's not crashing it looks off.  When you writing a book :)